# Yii2 admin pretty urls not working in nginx

Tags: nginx, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have deployed yii2 in nginx server and working fine..I can access the admin section by /admin url but no other urls under /admin is not working. I have enabled pretty urls in the application, what could be the nginx config I need to change

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your nginx conf ?

I also faced same issue, do you use this conf ?

```
server {
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 128M;

listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

server_name mysite.local;
root        /path/to/basic/web;
index       index.php;

access_log  /path/to/basic/log/access.log;
error_log   /path/to/basic/log/error.log;

location / {
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
#location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
#    try_files $uri =404;
#}
#error_page 404 /404.html;

# deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~* /\. {
    deny all;
}
```

}

[more at here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)

Comment: Yes I have the same conf